Optimal layout for a horizontal product card
I’m wireframing the product list of an e-commerce app. The client requested a horizontal card layout with a lot of information that is necessary to display:

Product image
"Sale" badge
Product name
Rating
Shipping and stock information
Price (with discount, unit cost and cost per area)
"Compare" button
"Add to cart" button

Could you please give me some input how can I improve the layout of the card?
Thanks!


design reviews are off topic for this site, but at first sight you're using very little space for such amount of information. I'd make the height much bigger, close to twice the current height. Besides, on a phone this would become a nightmare, so start with mobile first and then go to desktop

I recommend adopting a three-part layout, akin to Dell's approach: dedicate one section to the image and offer, the middle for item description, and the final for pricing. Additionally, consider making the "Add to Cart" button primary while "Compare" is a tertiary button.
However, a word of caution: horizontal cards can lead to a poorer user experience, as they generally require more visual effort to navigate compared to vertical cards.

Vertical vs. Horizontal Cards: Which Are Better?
